# How to set the replacement font in HTML?

Tags: html, replace, fonts

I'm making a HTML banner with Edge Animace CC. I've set my font to droid-serif.

It works fine until I test it on a Nokia Lumia 610.
It gets replaced by a different font which replaces the character "**Ž**" with symbols.

So can I **replace/set the substitute font with proper one** in html which shows character "**ž**"?

Comment: check the font's glyphs list if its supports your character

Comment: The main font "droid-serif" supports that character, but windows phone doesn't show that font, so it gets replaced with substitute, wich doesn't support "Ž"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out which font available in windows phone supports that character,and in your CSS font style append it along with droid-serif.

```
font-family: "droid-serif", "windows-phone-font-name" , serif;
```

If that don't work, you should try Web Fonts (maybe Google Web Fonts) that specifically supports your required character, and use that for it.

(** I would comment but I cannot yet **)